# Display a Single Value from the output through a key in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I wrote a python script that gets the content of a particular url using Bs and requests module: the code is as follows:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

page = requests.get(" ")
res = page.text
def srs(res):
  repls = ('srs(', ''), ('});', '')
  s = res
  rep1 = reduce(lambda a, kv: a.replace(*kv), repls, s)
  rep2 = rep1.replace('[', '')
  print rep2
srs(res)
```

The code works fine and does what it is intended to, the output is as follows:

```
{"term":"allbany","moresuggestions":517,"autoSuggestInstance":null,"suggestions":{"group":"CITY_GROUP","entities":{"geoId":"1000000000000000355","destinationId":"1508137","landmarkCityDestinationId":null,"type":"CITY","caption":"Albany, Albany County, United States of America","redirectPage":"DEFAULT_PAGE","latitude":42.650249,"longitude":-73.753578,"name":"Albany"},{"geoId":"1000000000006058117","destinatioId":"1503240","landmarkCityDestinationId":null,"type":"CITY","caption":"Albany, Georgia, United States of America","redirectPage":"DEFAULT_PAGE","latitude":31.57695,"longitude":-84.151199,"name":"Albany"},{"geoId":"1000000000006135421"}.....
```

However is there a way where I could call a single value through a particular  key.
For Eg suppose print rep2['term'] should display 'allbany' or rep2['moresuggestions'] should display '517'.I tried converting the output to Json and then displaying but it gives the error "String Indices must be int"

Comment: Did you try `page.json()` ?

Comment: yes, error:"unicode' object has no attribute 'json'", i tried json.dumps too

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

- Convert the output to json, assuming the value is `rep2` (as in your question)
- Use `json.loads` to convert it to Python object -- `rep2_parsed = json.loads(rep2)`
- You'll be able to use expressions like `rep2_parsed['term']`

Comment: Tried doing that,but it gives the error "Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes:"

Comment: there are no single quotes in the output, but there are some values without quotes for eg. 517

Comment: @AustinJoy Actually, upon further inspection, your `resp2` contain HTML tags like `<br>` inside the supposedly json string... you'll need to parse those out before running `json.loads`.

Comment: that isnt there in the main code, however there are some values without quotes.

Comment: @AustinJoy Well, regardless, you'll want to make sure that the value of `rep2` is a valid JSON (try https://jsonlint.com/), and that all property names are enclosed in double quotes. As for boolean/numeric values, they can appear as is (without quotes).